# Setting scroll step/jump/snap distance with html/css

Tags: html, css, scroll

I swear I've done this before, but maybe it was in the pre-standards bad old days. Now I can't even figure out the keywords to find possible workarounds.

So I have a table that is in a wrapper so that the x-overflow is inside the wrapper instead of expanding the window.  Let's say each column is hard-set with css to be 150px.  I want it so that when horizontally scrolling the wrapper, the scrollbar "jumps" 150 pixels so that the right edge of the next column is aligned with the left margin of the wrapper. In other words, you scroll by column, not by pixel, so that the left-side of the viewport is never a partial column.

By extension, it would be ideal if this could be variable-width jumping so that the columns aren't forced to be a unified width, and I'd like to have this and all of the above for vertical scrolling as well.

I thought this was a standard but overlooked option for css or at least a deprecated html style attribute, but like I said, now I can't even find the idea/concept when I Google they keywords that come to mind.

Any help (even somewhat hackish ones that get me started) is appreciated.

Comment: I think the keyword I was missing is "step size" but all results seem to be mobile or mouse-wheel specific....

Comment: I don't really remember such an attribute, but you can definitely create the functionality with a bit of Javascript. You definitely should go that route if you want to make it jump by a variable width.

Comment: I definitly don't have a problem with using (good) javascript for such an effect, but always prefer to lean on js for style to fine-tune the css rather than rely on it to handle the entire effect. Which is to say, get as far as possible via css and use js to get the numbers right.  But that's a preference and personal guideline, not a rule.  I feel like creating such effects totally with js not only contributes to browser/programming misfires, but also discourages css inovation/adoption. But I digress.  Still hunting for any solution at this point.

Comment: Another keyword may be "snap to", but again, all examples seem to be touch screen related.  Getting closer, though, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that with CSS. Your only option is intercepting the scroll event on the target element and implementing your own scroll functionality with javascript, like this:

`addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {/*Your code here*/});`

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event

Answer (score 0):

This ain't exactly CSS, but you can use the DOM attribute `scrollLeft` (and also `scrollTop` if you need that direction).

For more information and a bit of an example, you can refer to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft).